# How to compare values in different objects jq

Tags: json, compare, jq

JSON :

```
{"blockHistory":[10, 12, 14, 17],
"hashrateHistory":[
{"hr":1,"time":9},
{"hr":2,"time":10},
{"hr":3,"time":11},
{"hr":4,"time":12},
{"hr":5,"time":13},
{"hr":6,"time":14},
{"hr":7,"time":15}
]
```

I want to get hr for every value from blockHistory where time from hashrateHistory is the biggest time <= blockHistory value.

This is what i have.
I don't know how to get the lastHR

```
 [{lastHr: .hashrateHistory[].hr, time: .blockHistory[]}] | sort_by(.time)
```

result i want:

```
[
  {
    "lastHr": 2,
    "time": 10
  },
  {
    "lastHr": 4,
    "time": 12
  },
  {
    "lastHr": 6,
    "time": 14
  },
  {
    "lastHr": 7,
    "time": 17
  }

]
```

Comment: It should be better now.

Comment: I'm just curious, what does this data represent?

Comment: History of some event (block) and history of values ​​of some parameters (hashrate), but it's just an exercise not any practical thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(.hashrateHistory | sort_by(.time)) as $hashrate
| .blockHistory | map(
    . as $max_time
    | $hashrate
    | map(select(.time <= $max_time))[-1]
    | {lastHr: .hr, time: $max_time}
)
```

For each element of block, iterate over sorted/saved hashrate. Select only the last matching element and create an object within the block map.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach which uses [`group_by`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#group_by(path_expression)) after building an intermediate result

```
  .blockHistory as $b
| [ .hashrateHistory[] | .group = [ $b[] < .time ] ] 
| group_by(.group) 
| map(max_by(.time) | del(.group)) 
| sort_by(.time)
```

Based on your original attempt this includes a final `sort_by` but it might not be necessary.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc7RCoIwFAbge5/iMLxQkOHUkqTueweR2ErSUrTNIFGf3abpKWKcm@//dzi3xzgCUFFU5/sxV00lW@AKTGH0EAPNuMokb9IlihPogV5l9azhoHNTaNkDbfIyhUQ//WtOT6K1Pj17spLXVslfs05dW6@5pMVamTuqks23MI4d@T2KRDFzHWCenkBPmDgG@btOd4yOZJJEzCHTFhLtBmchbyXmovloDC1A89A2aD7aFi1AC9E2g5EMbw)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution oriented towards time-efficiency on the assumption that the .blockHistory array is sufficiently large and "interesting" to offset the up-front investment in the construction of a dictionary ($dict) and the sorting of the .hashrateHistory array by `.time`.

The case of an exact match is handled using a dictionary ($dict), and the other case is handled using the built-in function `bsearch` for conducting a binary search:

```
.hashrateHistory as $hashrateHistory
| INDEX($hashrateHistory[]; .time) as $dict
| ($hashrateHistory | sort_by(.time) ) as $sorted
| ($sorted | map(.time)) as $sorted_time
| ($sorted | map(.hr)) as $sorted_hr
| .blockHistory
| map( . as $t
       | $dict[$t|tostring]
       | if . then {lastHr: .hr, time }
         else (-2 - ($sorted_time | bsearch($t))) as $i
         | {lastHr: $sorted_hr[$i], time: $t}
         end )
```